# What does document["Some Name"] really do?

Tags: javascript, html, document

This code

```
<img name="n1" src="" />
<h1 name="n2">a header</h1>
<script>
document["n1"].src = "http://x.y/picture.jpg";
document["n2"].innerHTML = "Boo";
</script>
```

Does something different for the `<img>` and `<h1>` tags.  The picture `src` is changed as expected by the `document["n1"].src` line.  But the heading `innerHTML` is not changed as expected by the `document["n2"].innerHTML` line.  What does `document["some string"]` really return?

Comment: First and foremost it accesses the property `some string` of the `document` object. Then the question is what are the properties and what do they correspond to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In JavaScript, `object["string"]` access the property `'string'` on `object`. This can be used to access many different properties on many different objects, and is like treating the object as a hash map of values. For the `document` object, this will get loaded with certain properties by default, like elements with the `name` attribute. At least for some browsers (I have no idea which subset).

That said, the [`name` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.name) isn't a valid attribute on an `<h1>` tag, so the document does not load that into `document["name"]` value.

The name attribute is valid on the following elements:

- `<a>` - Attribute deprecated in HTML 4, obsolete in HTML5
- `<applet>` - Element obsolete in HTML5
- `<button>`
- `<form>` - Attribute deprecated in HTML 4, [returned in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-form-element.html#attr-form-name)
- `<frame>` - Element obsolete in HTML5
- `<iframe>`
- `<img>` - Attribute deprecated in HTML 4, obsolete in HTML5
- `<input>`
- `<map>`
- `<meta>` - Not the same `name` attribute
- `<object>`
- `<param>` - Not the same `name` attribute
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`

For each of these elements, if they have a `name` attribute, they will be added to the document, as you can see. The preferred way to get this elements, though, is using [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName)

Comment: I'd mark `<a>`'s name as deprecated too, at least that's what the Firefox console outputs when putting a name attribute on an anchor element.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté The deprecated notes are actually about the elements themselves being deprecated. The `name` attribute is, however, itself obsolete for most elements. I'll mark those as well

Comment: Oh I see. The `frame` element is deprecated in HTML5, wasn't aware about the `applet` one. Names are useful on input/select/textarea elements to be able to serialize the data for get/post requests. For anchor tags, the name attribute allowed to use hash anchors to link to them, but an ID is preferred for that now.

Comment: That's a really good answer (+1) that lacks just a couple of things. For completeness, there are three other elements in HTML5 for which a name attribute is valid: `<fieldset>`, `<keygen>` and `<output>`. Also it lacks a link to a spec defining how the document object supports named properties. That is at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which

Comment: It seems that the HTML5 obsolete `name` attribute on the `<embed>` object is also relevant to the list of named properties on the document object.

Comment: Thanks! This is a better answer than I was expecting! :)